# DLC Quest disabling sexy outfits?

Tags: dlc-quest

In DLC Quest I recently bought the sexy outfit pack. It's funny but it kinda ruins the mood, so I was wondering if there's a way to disable it. I know it says "No refunds" but is there a way?